# Array inheritance problem in Zend_Config_Ini

Tags: php, zend-framework

Probably it comes from parse_ini_file()

> [production]
>
> resources.cachemanager.default.frontend.name
>   = "Core" resources.cachemanager.default.backend.name
>   = "Memcached" resources.cachemanager.default.backend.servers.0.host
>   = "live server 1" resources.cachemanager.default.backend.servers.0.port
>   = 11211 resources.cachemanager.default.backend.servers.1.host
>   = "live server 2" resources.cachemanager.default.backend.servers.1.port
>   = 11211
>
> [development:production]
>
> resources.cachemanager.default.backend.servers.0.host
>   = "dev server 1" resources.cachemanager.default.backend.servers.0.port
>   = 11211

for development section you will have "dev server 1" and "live server 2".
I understand that it's logical to have such a result, but I need to reset parent tree somehow.

Is there any way?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for this issue too

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can read the development section of your ini without inheritance from production as follows:

```
    $conf = new Zend_Config_Ini(
                    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini',
                    'development',
                    array('skipExtends' => true) // default value is false
    );
    var_dump($conf->resources->cachemanager->default->backend->servers->toArray());
    var_dump($conf->resources->cachemanager->default->frontend->toArray());
```

The above will result in:

```
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'host' => string 'live server 1' (length=13)
          'port' => string '11211' (length=5)

   // and an error because there will be no frontend if you need it.
```

If you want to use ini values from production also, but you don't want to have "live server 2" in development, you could read the two sections independently, unset the servers from production and merge it with development:

```
   $productionIniOnly = new Zend_Config_Ini(
                    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini',
                    'production',
                    array('skipExtends' => true,'allowModifications'=>true)
    );

    unset($productionIniOnly->resources->cachemanager->default->backend->servers);

    $developmentIniOnly = new Zend_Config_Ini(
                    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini',
                    'development',
                    array('skipExtends' => true,'allowModifications'=>true)
    );

    $developmentIni = $developmentIniOnly->merge($productionIniOnly);

    var_dump($developmentIni->resources->cachemanager->default->backend->servers->toArray());
    var_dump($developmentIni->resources->cachemanager->default->frontend->toArray());
```

The above will give:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'host' => string 'live server 1' (length=13)
      'port' => string '11211' (length=5)
array
  'name' => string 'Core' (length=4)
```

Hope this will be of use to you.

Comment: I appreciate your time, but I was asking about how to do that in ini level.

Comment: @Aram. So i think you should indicate in your question that it must be at ini level, not in php as it is not clear.